# Python TCP Client to connect to Servo Motor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcpclient, servo

I have a servo motor connected via ethernet to my computer. I am trying to write a TCP client in Python to connect to it and send it commands via strings. For example, sending the string "?90.1" should prompt the device to return an array of parameters. My current issue is I'm unsure if I'm making a connection or if the device is receiving any messages. I have verified the correct IP address and port.

Here is my current code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('192.168.12.61', 10001)
print("Connecting to {}".format(server_address))
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    # Initial test to see if connection has been made. Will send ?90.1
    message = str.encode("?90.1")
    print("Sending message {}".format(message))
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for response. Expected response is K-parameters
    data = sock.recv(32)
    print("Received {}".format(data.decode()))

finally:
    print("Closing socket")
    sock.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
(CMController) C:\Users\Andy\PycharmProjects\CMController>python CMController.py
Connecting to ('192.168.12.61', 10001)
Sending message b'?90.1'
Received ?90.1
Closing socket
```

Comment: What’s the make+model of the servo motor controller? Does the manufacturer have any sample code you can use to verify the controller is working?

Comment: It's a CoolMuscle servo motor. I was provided with a C# application that was able to verify that the controller is working. I'm trying to create a Python application that can do the same as a personal project.

Comment: Great that eliminates the ‘does it even work’ question :-) So can you use a network tracing tool like wireshark to see exactly what’s sent? Did you try ending with a \n?